# RGB, photoresistor, and if-else loop?

Tags: loops, if-statement, rgb

I am having a little trouble with a program of mine. My circuit consists of (mainly) an arduino UNO, two RGB LEDs, and a photoresistor. My current code(programmed in c++) operates the hardware as so: When the lights in the room are on, the two LEDs alternate blue/off once per second in a loop. When the lights are off, or the photoresistor is not sensing any light, both LEDs turn on, and stay on, red.
My code:

```
int prPin = A0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(prPin,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int prVal = analogRead(prPin);
  Serial.write(prVal);
    if(prVal>450)
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8,LOW);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(5,LOW);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,LOW);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,LOW);
      delay(10);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is when the lights turn off, the LEDs will not operate according to the "else" statement/loop until it finishes going through the "if" statement/loop.
Any suggestions or answers are appreciated. I'm an open book, so I'll take anything you guys give me.

Comment: I suggest that you join [Arduino Stack Exchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/), they're much more familiar with the set of tools that actually work on Arduino.  Here, you're likely to get a lot of suggestions that would work perfectly on a full-sized Linux desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the [following](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvoidDelay).

Using `millis` instead of `delay` is way more powerful and efficient ! It will also be easy to fix your issue since the loop won't be delayed anymore, therefore no delay switching from one state to the other.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis) are more details about the millis method.

I suggest you take the answer from the [copy of your question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16369/rgbs-photoresistors-and-delays/16378#16378) on Arduino SE.

Comment: I replaced the "delay" commands with what you had suggested, but I got the error message: "too many arguments to function 'long unsigned int millis()'".

Comment: I suggest you actually read the document I referenced. You cannot directly replace the calls like that.

Comment: I read the document, but it does not include information on how to use it as a delay (if that is what you mean).

Comment: @Shiori_Toshiko Just edited my answer with more documentation + code

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed to solve my problem.